# Failed to instantiate module kendo.directives using JSPM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, ecmascript-6, jspm

I'm trying to load Kendo UI *All* integration with Angular to be able to use its built-in UI widget directives.

I've installed the package using the following command: `jspm install kendo-ui`

In some file, I'm importing *jQuery*, *Angular* and *Kendo UI*:

```
import jquery from "jquery";
import ng from "angular";
import kendoUi from "kendo-ui";

angular.module("common", [
    "kendo.directives"
]);
```

My `config.js` looks as follows:

```
...
 map: {
    "kendo-ui": "github:kendo-labs/bower-kendo-ui@2016.1.125"
 }
...
```

...and when I load the app I get the whole `"Failed to instantiate module kendo.directives"` error message.

It seems like Kendo UI Core code is executed before Angular is present, or I think so, because Kendo UI's documentation states:

> To activate the Angular bindings, load angular.js before you load
>   Kendo UI. Therefore, load the scripts in the order shown below.

In addition, I've tried to fix the issue adding a `meta` property to *config.js*:

```
meta: {
    'kendo-angular': {
        exports: 'kendo',
        deps: [
            "jquery",
            "angular",
            "kendo-ui"
        ]
    }
}
```

...and an entry to `map`:

```
"kendo-angular": "github:kendo-labs/bower-kendo-ui@2016.1.125/js/kendo.angular.min"
```

Now it seems like `kendo.angular.min.js` is loaded, but it's throwing the following error message: `"Cannot read property 'jQuery' of undefined"`...

### Update

It seems like the issue isn't a load order at all: without using the trial-error I did yesterday (the thing about `map`  and `meta`), the error `"Failed to instantiate module kendo.directives"` shouldn't happen because the package is loading `kendo.ui.core`, which already includes the module `kendo.directives`.

In the other hand, I've tried to put a breakpoint on unminified version of the so-called file, and the result is the code that defines Angular `kendo.directives` module is never executed, but some other part of the source code, when I set a breakpoint, it's hit and Angular is present in the global scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve the issue.

*On `config.js`*:

```
  ...
  meta: {
    "kendo-ui": {
        deps: ["kendo.ui.core"]
    },
    "kendo.ui.core": {
      "deps": [
        "angular"
      ]
    }
  }
  ...
  map: {
    "kendo-ui": "github:kendo-labs/bower-kendo-ui@2016.1.125",
    "kendo.ui.core": "github:kendo-labs/bower-kendo-ui@2016.1.125/src/js/kendo.ui.core"
  }
```

After reviewing the `kendo.ui.core` source code and trying to debug it, I discovered that their `"kendo.ui.core"` *AMD* module is defined but never required by code. Thus, all modules grouped by the `"kendo.ui.core"` *AMD* module were never loaded.

This is the reason behind manually adding `"kendo.ui.core"` to both `meta` and `map` and force `"kendo-ui"` to depend on `"kendo.ui.core"`...

I still think that this isn't the definitive solution. [I've already posted an issue on Kendo UI GitHub repository](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/1421) to let things move on in the right direction.